How to construct solverManager properly and is it possible to use abstruct class to dynamically terminate the solver
I am customizing the TimeFold employee scheduling sample. The EmployeeScheduleResource
constructor injects a SolverManager object. The minimum source code is as follows:
public class EmployeeScheduleResource {
    SolverManager<EmployeeSchedule, String> solverManager;
    SolutionManager<EmployeeSchedule, HardMediumSoftScore> solutionManager;

    @Inject
    public EmployeeScheduleResource(SolverManager<EmployeeSchedule, String> solverManager,SolutionManager<EmployeeSchedule, HardMediumSoftScore> solutionManager) {
        this.solverManager = solverManager
        this.solutionManager = solutionManager;

    }
}

But I need a solver manager, that takes following settings from XML file:
<termination>
  <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>30</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
  <unimprovedScoreDifferenceThreshold>0hard/0medium/1soft</unimprovedScoreDifferenceThreshold>
</termination>

Currently, I have replaced the following constructor as follows:
@Inject
public EmployeeScheduleResource(SolverManager<EmployeeSchedule, String> solverManager,
        SolutionManager<EmployeeSchedule, HardMediumSoftScore> solutionManager) {
    SolverConfig solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("solverConfig.xml");
    this.solverManager = SolverManager.create(solverConfig, new SolverManagerConfig());
    this.solutionManager = solutionManager;

}

I believe this is not a proper way to solve this problem. Would anybody give me a suggestion to solve the problem in an appropriate way?
Also can we use the AbstractTermination<EmployeeRoster> class for termination handling? Earlier in Optaplanner we extends it and implement our logic. If we use the unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit and unimprovedScoreDifferenceThreshold, then it's fixed and we can't calculate the score improvement at run time. I have to decide whether the % of score not improved from the current score for a period of time.

This is what SolverConfigOverride is for.  This is how the code would look utilizing SolverConfigOverride:
public class EmployeeScheduleResource {
    SolverManager<EmployeeSchedule, String> solverManager;
    SolutionManager<EmployeeSchedule, HardMediumSoftScore> solutionManager;

    @Inject
    public EmployeeScheduleResource(SolverManager<EmployeeSchedule, String> solverManager,SolutionManager<EmployeeSchedule, HardMediumSoftScore> solutionManager) {
        this.solverManager = solverManager
        this.solutionManager = solutionManager;

    }
    
    public void solve(String id, EmployeeSchedule problem, SolverConfigOverride terminationProperties) {
        solverManager.solveBuilder()
                     .withProblem(problem)
                     .withProblemId(id)
                     .withConfigOverride(terminationProperties)
                     .run();
    }
}

Example usage:
@Inject
EmployeeScheduleResource employeeScheduleResource;

public void test() {
    EmployeeSchedule problem = generateProblem();
    employeeScheduleResource.solve("0", problem, new SolverConfigOverride()
        .withTerminationConfig(
            new TerminationConfig()
                .withUnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit(30)
                .withUnimprovedScoreDifferenceThreshold("0hard/0medium/1soft")
        ));
}


side note: src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml is automatically picked up (with its configuration applied to the injected/autowired solver manager) in both Quarkus and Spring Boot.

Basically, I need to implement like this. If the current score during calculation is 1000. And the percent of calculation improvement is 10% that is 100 within 1 minutes, then the calculation will continue. Otherwise, it will terminate.
